# How to use GATE facades in LUMEN (Laravel 6.2)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to create an ACL with Lumen.
I want to use the built-in gates/policies to do so.
I've been following the official Lumen Docs:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization

and Laravel Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization

to do so. They say I need to register both facades and the gate facade in order to use Gates.

I have the following code inside my AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Boot the authentication services for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function boot()
     {
       // Here you may define how you wish users to be authenticated for your Lumen
       // application. The callback which receives the incoming request instance
       // should return either a User instance or null. You're free to obtain
       // the User instance via an API token or any other method necessary.

       $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
         $key = 'pawifjopawiejfpoaiwejfpoji';
         $jwt = preg_replace('/^Bearer (.*)/', '$1', $request->header('Authorization'));
         $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, ['HS256']);

         return User::where('email', $decoded->email)->first();
       });

       $this->registerPolicies();

       Gate::define('edit-settings', function($user){
         return $user->isAdmin;
       });
     }
}
```

And I have the bootstrap/app.php set like so, with `$app->withFacades()` uncommented:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__)
))->bootstrap();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);

 $app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//     App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

 $app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

And when I now run any http-request with RESTClient (www.restclient.net) against my Lumen API, I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::registerPolicies()
```

I googled quite a lot on this issue and found some solutions, but none of them worked for me. 
Please help

Comment: because your AuthServiceProvider doesnt have that method ... it doesn't extend the Provider that Laravel uses for that, it just extends the base Service Provider

Comment: @lagbox Thanks, but how/where can I deal with this issue in the lumen codebase?

Comment: if you don't have any policies there would be no reason to run `registerPolicies` even if it did exist

Answer (score 1):

Your provider doesn't have that method. This is the entire `AuthServiceProvider` that Laravel uses as its base for `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [];

    /**
     * Register the application's policies.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerPolicies()
    {
        foreach ($this->policies() as $key => $value) {
            Gate::policy($key, $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the policies defined on the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function policies()
    {
        return $this->policies;
    }
}
```

`registerPolicies` isn't doing anything special. It just spins through `$policies` and registers them; you can do this yourself.

> "Unlike Laravel, Lumen does not have a `$policies` array on its `AuthServiceProvider`. However, you may still call the `policy` method on the `Gate` facade from within the provider's `boot` method" - [Lumen 6.x Docs - Authorization - Defining Policies](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization)